# Value between 0 - 1 happens too fast on Scroll

Tags: javascript

Based on the mousewheel event, I need to get values between 0 - 1.

An example I have tried works, it gives me 0 - 1, however it is way too fast.  How would I slow this down and possibly give it inertia?

```
var r = 0
function onMouseWheel(e) {  

    e();
    r += e.deltaY / 500;
    r = clamp(0, 1, r);

    console.log('r is', r)
}
```

The values I get is below, but happens way too quickly on mouse scroll.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you divide `e.deltaY` through a greater value than 500? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/11320/

Comment: @Mugen87 I did try to do a greater value than 500, but it seems anytime I scroll fast quickly it goes from 0 - 1 instantly

Comment: Start a timer when logging the value and don't print again till the timer is expired.

Answer (score 0):

Made a boolean. The console message will only be printed when this boolean is true. The boolean is set to false when a message is printed and a timer of 1000ms runs to set the boolean back to true after 1 second. This way you will only print 1 time each second.

```js
var i = 0;
var doOnScroll = true;
window.onload = function() {
  var scrollable = document.getElementById('scrollable');
  scrollable.onscroll = function() {
    if(doOnScroll) {
      console.log('scrolling:' + i);
      i++;
      doOnScroll = false;
      setTimeout(function(){
        doOnScroll = true;
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
};
```

```css
.scrollable {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable" class="scrollable">
  <P>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu pellentesque nibh. Sed eu condimentum ligula. Sed feugiat hendrerit tortor ac elementum. Fusce gravida dolor hendrerit, porttitor ligula non, aliquet augue. Etiam vulputate massa eleifend
    ex venenatis lobortis. Suspendisse vestibulum sit amet ipsum id efficitur. Nulla tempor neque elit, vel ultricies lorem placerat sed. Pellentesque sit amet nunc porttitor, placerat lorem id, vehicula metus. Aenean quam augue, dictum non nunc quis,
    condimentum molestie magna.
  </P>
  <P>
    Quisque in sem malesuada, condimentum sapien in, congue purus. Praesent sed luctus felis. Nunc interdum mi vitae euismod feugiat. Maecenas condimentum pharetra nulla sit amet suscipit. Cras et mattis enim. Fusce in dolor congue, pellentesque lectus non,
    scelerisque nulla. Nunc lobortis egestas aliquet. Pellentesque sit amet venenatis nisl. Maecenas sit amet quam ante. Praesent sed erat elit. Curabitur efficitur consequat enim, ac ultrices mauris blandit at. Vivamus a hendrerit turpis, quis tincidunt
    enim. Cras facilisis neque eu ipsum fermentum, dignissim posuere erat tempor. Donec elementum porta tortor quis euismod. Praesent laoreet tristique sollicitudin.
    <P>
    </P>
    Mauris fermentum, mi at feugiat viverra, ligula ante lobortis nibh, id eleifend est ipsum non sem. Nulla a est turpis. Mauris ullamcorper tempus tortor, sit amet faucibus ex ornare ac. Vivamus rhoncus urna velit, sit amet mattis ligula cursus in. Donec
    interdum vehicula lacinia. Nulla facilisis feugiat risus pulvinar porttitor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer efficitur risus vel neque facilisis vestibulum. Ut molestie vestibulum
    mauris, bibendum feugiat massa scelerisque id. Nunc quis magna congue, condimentum arcu quis, eleifend est.
  </P>
</div>
```